# Does postgresql release (advisory) locks after a DISCARD ALL; command?

Tags: postgresql, locking, postgresql-9.6

Does postgresql release (advisory) locks after a `DISCARD ALL;` command?

It seems like it doesn't from [this mail discussion I found](https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=pgsql-hackers@postgresql.org&q=subject:%22Re%5C%3A+%5C%5BHACKERS%5C%5D+%5C%5Bbugfix%5C%5D+DISCARD+ALL+does+not+release+advisory+locks%22&o=newest&f=1). But I was wondering if anyone could tell me if this was changed or fixed in a new release since [nov 2008](https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=pgsql-hackers@postgresql.org&q=subject:%22Re%5C%3A+%5C%5BHACKERS%5C%5D+%5C%5Bbugfix%5C%5D+DISCARD+ALL+does+not+release+advisory+locks%22&o=newest&f=1)?

Comment: according to docs it is supposed to - why you ask? you still observer the bug in mailling list?..

Comment: Yes, I should have looked a bit further. I remember looking at the discard documentation page but I guess I overlooked it. Or maybe I just had a quick look at the wrong version of the docs only. My bad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-discard.html

> Releases all temporary resources associated with the current session
>   and resets the session to its initial state. Currently, this has the
>   same effect as executing the following sequence of statements:
>
> ```
> SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION DEFAULT;
> RESET ALL;
> DEALLOCATE ALL;
> CLOSE ALL;
> UNLISTEN *;
> SELECT pg_advisory_unlock_all();
> DISCARD PLANS;
> DISCARD SEQUENCES;
> DISCARD TEMP;
> ```

supposedly?..

Comment: Well, I guess I should have RTFM. Sorry 'bout that ;)

Comment: mo worries - I thought you are talking about some bug